# IllegalArgumentException when trying to run an OpenGL ES 2.0 application

Tags: android, opengl-es

When I add the following line to my GLSurfaceView class I get an IllegalArgumentException from some random place. I don't know where the problem is because it doesn't give a stack trace.

```
setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
```

What else do I need to do to get an OpenGL ES 2.0 application to work?

NB: I'm trying to run the application on the emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenGL ES 2.0 isn't supported by the Android emulator.

See the post by Romain Guy (Android framework engineer) - http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/58a855ec8aba4c33